# Cannot transpile TypeScript containing async await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typescript, async-await, tsc

When trying to transpile the following TypeScript code containing `async` and `await` keywords

```
async function foo() {
    await bar();
}
```

I get the following error

```
src/aa.ts(1,7): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/aa.ts(2,11): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

The result is a .js file with this content

```
async;
function foo() {
    await;
    bar();
}
```

I'm using these tsc options: `-t es6 -m commonjs`, following instructions on [this MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/11/03/what-about-asyncawait/). I have TypeScript 1.8.9 installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the TypeScript compiler did not recognize the `async` and `await` keywords. This happened even though the TypeScript compiler version was of the correct version.

What I did to solve this is uninstall tsc and install typescript globally:

```
npm uninstall --global tsc
npm install --global typescript
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue with an asynchronous arrow function:

```
async resource_type => some_value
// error TS1005: ',' expected.
```

Typescript was happy once I wrapped my function parameter in parenthesis:

`async (resource_type) => some_value`