# ts Cannot find name 'async' via TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm using TypeScript But I have This Error:

```
[ts] Cannot find name 'async'
```

And This is my Code:

```
async someAsyncCode() {
    let asyncFn = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve: Function) => { resolve(2); });
    }
    // should log `2`
    console.log(await asyncFn());
}
```

This is my Packeges.json:

```
{
  "name": "simple-typescript-gulp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/aliparhamnia/simple-typescript-gulp.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/aliparhamnia/simple-typescript-gulp/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/aliparhamnia/simple-typescript-gulp#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.41",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.32",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.13",
    "async": "^2.4.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.0",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "json-query": "^2.2.2",
    "nano": "^6.2.0",
    "node-telegram-bot-api": "^0.27.0",
    "q": "^1.5.0",
    "sessionstorage": "0.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^7.0.12",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "ts-node": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

But I Can use Asynce Like Blow and haven't any error and I Don't Know Why I have Error In above Example

> const x = async () => await getmessage();

Comment: check your target platform in tsconfig.json or .csproject if it visual studio

Comment: Have you installed the `typescript` module globally?

Comment: yes, but still I have error

Comment: could you please share your TypeScript version or package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved With This:

```
var test = async() => {
    let asyncFn = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve: Function) => { resolve(2); });
    }
    // should log `2`
    console.log(await asyncFn());

}
```

And I Called With:

```
test();
```

And I haven't any Error

Comment: weird, because then you are not using native TypeScript async functions.

Comment: maybe worth it to try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423600/cannot-transpile-typescript-containing-async-await

Comment: I used That but , not work, In my case Solved with above code, thank you